# Open Port 1433 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-4, server, port-forwarding

I have tried to connect to MSSQl Database from raspberry pi. However, I have a few errors coming. I try to telnet the server ip address like that.

```
telnet 192.168.10.70 1433
Trying 192.168.10.70
Connected to 192.168.10.70
Escape character is '^]'
```

However, to check if a server has port 1433 listening, I run `netstat -ano -p |find “1433”` in command prompt but the error is `No such file or directory`.

So I think running the netstat command on Pi returns no result because there is no port 1433 open on Pi, not server. So anyone knows how to open the port in Pi?

I have used ufw but after it is enabled, I cannot ssh. Do we really need ufw? That's the part I am confusing.

Comment: You don't need to open port 1433 on the RPi, it will use an ephemeral port to connect with your external server. The firewall is always done on the server not the client.

Comment: Ok thank you. Then how should I solve this issue? any suggestion?

Comment: Look at the server not the client.

Comment: Could you please tell us why you can't use ssh?

Comment: I am not sure about your question @NomadMaker. The thing is I have problem that cannot connect to server although server side is allowed the port I want to connect. Now I have solve it and it is that after I have changed the server from hostname to ipaddress in pyodbc portion in my case.

Answer (score 3):

> I run `netstat -ano -p |find “1433”` in command prompt but the error is **No such file or directory**.

Yes, because `find` does not process data via standard input, and what `find "1433"` means is to look for a file called `1433` in the current directory.  If it is there, it will simply spit out `1433`, otherwise you get that error.

Since you've redirected the output of `netstat`, that is discarded without you seeing what it is. So that line is a nonsense command and does not do anything useful.

If you want to search the output of a command, pipe it to `grep`, not `find`.

As per the manpage, `netstat` is considered obsolete in favour of `ss`.  If you want to look for connections to a particular remote port:

```
ss -atp '( dport = :1443 )'
# Beware the single quotes and spaces inside parentheses are needed.
```

However, this will only show *existing connections*.  It cannot tell you if some remote server you are not connected to has a specific port accessible to you, because that is not what `ss` is for. It is what `nmap` and `arp` are for though. If you know the IP address of the server, you can check if TCP port 1433 is open there with:

```
nmap -sT -p1433 x.x.x.x
```

Where `x.x.x.x` is the IP address.  If you don't know exactly what it is but it is on a local subnet, you can use a CIDR notation, eg. 192.168.0.0/16.

Comment: Thank you. It really clarify my doubt.